# JAXB java object to xml, create Pascal Case XML elements

Tags: java, spring, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

**Generated object from a wsdl through jaxb plugin**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "WebAuthenticationCredential", propOrder = {
    "key",
    "password"
})
public class WebAuthenticationCredential {

    @XmlElement(name = "Key", required = true)
    protected String key;
    @XmlElement(name = "Password", required = true)
    protected String password;
```

**Method:**

```
public RateReply getRates(
        Request sRequest) {

    try {
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<WebAuthenticationCredential> soapRateRequest =
                objectFactory.createRateRequest(sRequest);
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xmlContent = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(soapRateRequest);
        logger.info(xmlContent); // check below the response

        Reply rReply = (Reply) JAXBIntrospector
                .getValue(WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(serviceUri, soapRateRequest));
        handleErrors(rateReply);
        return rateReply;
    } catch (SoapFaultClientException e) {
        logger.error("Caught exception rates", e);
        throw new Exception("Failed calling service ", null);
    }
}
```

**createRequest method from ObjectFactory class which is generated by JAXB:**

```
   /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link RateRequest }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14", name = "PreAuthorizedRateRequest")
    public JAXBElement<RateRequest> createPreAuthorizedRateRequest(RateRequest value) {
        return new JAXBElement<RateRequest>(_PreAuthorizedRateRequest_QNAME, RateRequest.class, null, value);
```

**logger info for the xmlContent (printed with camel cases elements) is**

```
<JAXBElement>
    <name>PreRequest</name>
    <declaredType>Request</declaredType>
    <scope>javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope</scope>
    <value>
        <webAuthenticationDetail>
            <key>test</key>
            <password>password</password>
        </webAuthenticationDetail>
    </value>
</JAXBElement>
```

**Expected Output:** all the elements inside  should be pascal case (**W**ebAuthenticationDetail, **K**ey, **P**assword), does it possible with JAXB ??

```
<JAXBElement>
    <name>PreRequest</name>
    <declaredType>Request</declaredType>
    <scope>javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope</scope>
    <value>
        <WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <Key>test</Key>
            <Password>password</Password>
        </WebAuthenticationDetail>
    </value>
</JAXBElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default XmlMapper does not recognize the JAXB annotations. To enable them you need to register the module *JaxbAnnotationModule*.

Example:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(); 
xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

Comment: I added the XmlMapper just to convert the soapRequest to string and print that out in logs, the XmlMapper is not being used in the actual method. Are you referring to anything else ??

Comment: So the problem is that the values are not sent in Pascal case with this request: "WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(serviceUri, soapRateRequest)"? Then can you post the entire class of the "public RateReply getRates" method?